# How to get length of CLOB in Java/Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am working with a table (Oracle), that has a CLOB column. And I am using Hibernate to query the table. Here is a quick look at the class that I am using to map the Oracle table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="D2D_OPD_ORDERDELIVERY")
public class D2dOpdOrderDelivery implements Serializable {

// other column mappings omitted for brevity

@Column(name="POD_SIGNATURE_IMG", nullable=true)
@Lob
private Clob podSignatureImage;
```

I have successfully managed to run the Hibernate query, which returns a single row from the database:

```
// Create a Hibernate query (HQL)
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM D2dOpdOrderDelivery WHERE orderNumber = :orderNumber");
query.setParameter("orderNumber", orderNumber);
```

Elsewhere in my code, I perform a null check on my Clob - it is NOT null. Next, I try to get the length of my Clob. And this is where I run into a problem. I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209)
    oracle.sql.CLOB.getDBAccess(CLOB.java:1212)
    oracle.sql.CLOB.length(CLOB.java:223)
```

Sorry, I just don't understand why I am getting this error. I have already run my query (all the other fields in the row are present). Why can't I get the length of my CLOB?

Can someone please point out where I have gone wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after posting this question, I went back and searched the Internet some more. I thought I had done a pretty good job of that *before* I posted my question - but that is another matter...

Anyway, I found a useful link here:
http://www.javavids.com/video/how-to-read-data-from-blob-using-jpa-hibernate.html

And the change I made to my code:

```
@Column(name="POD_SIGNATURE_IMG", nullable=true)
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private char[] podSignatureImage;
```

I was then able to call .length on my char[]

Hope this is helpful to someone else...